# how to get async service call result in property getter in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service, properties

how can I get Async call result inside getter property?
my code sample is:

```
public  override  byte[] AddressBasedDocFile
        {
            get
            {   BaseInfoImplementationClient.AlfrescoServiceProxy.AlfrescoServicesProxyClient client = new BaseInfoImplementationClient.AlfrescoServiceProxy.AlfrescoServicesProxyClient();
                client.GetDataCompleted+=client_GetDataCompleted;
                client.GetDataAsync(this.ObjectId)  ;                       
            }
            set
            {
                base.AddressBasedDocFile = value;
            }
        }

        void client_GetDataCompleted(object sender, BaseInfoImplementationClient.AlfrescoServiceProxy.GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {   
            e.Result
        }
```

there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) that used tasks to do the job, but as I know, I can't change `client.GetDataAsync(this.ObjectId)` such that it returns a value, its really an asynchronous service call.

Comment: You cannot await properties so it should really be a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties cannot be declared asynchronous.

I recommend you should reconsider to change the getter to a async function e.g.

```
public async Task<bytes[]> GetAddressBasedDocFileAsync()
{
   ....
}
```

Getter should be fast to execute and should not throw exceptions. Performing a remote network call in a getter breaks these two best practices.